# Why is HTML in php function not visible in view source

Tags: php, function, session

function that runs when i want to edit a client status.

```
// deletes (sets inactive) client
function setClientStatus($client) {

if ($_GET['action'] == "setinactive") {

//database functions
$sql = 'UPDATE clients SET active="0" WHERE id="'. $client .'"';
$result = query($sql);
confirmQuery($result);

//set message to user to display
$_SESSION['error'] = false;
        $msgs[] = "Client was set to inactive and removed from the list!";
        $_SESSION['userMsg'] = $msgs;

}

    if ($_GET['action'] == "setactive") {

//database functions
$sql = 'UPDATE clients SET active="1" WHERE id="'. $client .'"';
$result = query($sql);
confirmQuery($result);

//set message to user to display
$_SESSION['error'] = false;
        $msgs[] = "Client was successfully restored!";
        $_SESSION['userMsg'] = $msgs;

}


//display clients page with changes made
redirect('?page=clients');



}
```

function that displays the message.

```
 //function that shows message and styles accordingly
 function message($msgs) {

if(!empty($msgs)) {


        foreach ($_SESSION['userMsg'] as $msg) {
            if ($_SESSION['error'] == false) {
            echo '<div class="noError">'.$msg.'</div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="error">'.$msg.'</div>';

            }
        }
    }
            unset($_SESSION['userMsg']);
            unset($_SESSION['error']);
 echo "hello";
}
```

here is where i call it in my page....

```
div class="pageContainer">

<?php
    //display messages
message($_SESSION['userMsg']);

?>
</div>
```

Now when everything is run and i select to edit and client status (or add client, edit client as they all have the same message section, just with different message)  i can see the message displayed on the screen.  i have a javascript script that will hid the message after 5 seconds, but it doesn't hide.  after viewing the page source i notice that the section of code is not visible.  again, i can see it clearly see the message that is suppose to be there "Client was set to inactive and removed from the list!" (or whatever message is set to display)  but it is NOT show in the view source html.

[pic of page loaded with message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7FP3F.jpg)

here is the view source.....

```
<div class="pageContainer">



    <div>
```

** updated **

this small example script renders the html, but my above script doesn't...

```
function setError() {
        $error[] = "Password field is to short";
            $_SESSION['userMsg'] = $error;
        //return $_SESSION['msg'];

        }

function message($errors){

    if(!empty($errors)) {
        foreach ($_SESSION['userMsg'] as $error) {
            echo $error.'<br>';
        }
    }
            unset($_SESSION['userMsg']);
}
```

Comment: Probably $_SESSION['userMsg'] is empty. Try to dump it's value to screen with print_r()

Comment: enable error reporting

Comment: it shows fine in action....it just isnt showin the view source portion which in turn is not allowing my javascript to hide the message after x amount of time because its not really there.....wierd

Comment: Is this being loaded with AJAX? View Source only shows the initial source, it doesn't show anything that was added to the DOM later.

Comment: Use the DOM inspector in the web console to see dynamic changes to the DOM.

Comment: no AJAX.  the session variable is loaded with another function, then in my page i call the message function which displays the session array if present.

Comment: unfortunately i don't know how to utilize the DOM inspector

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to display `$msgs`, so why you iterate `$_SESSION['userMsg']` ?

Probably the `$_SESSION['userMsg']` is null or empty. If you want to display the `$msgs` just iterate it. And later add to session if really needed. In you code, you always unset the `$_SESSION['userMsg']` in the end of function, probably it is always null then. I didn't see the `$_SESSION['userMsg']` needed here :

```
//function that shows message and styles accordingly
function message($msgs) {
    if(!empty($msgs)) {
        foreach ($msgs as $msg) {
            if ($_SESSION['error'] == false) {
            echo '<div class="noError">'.$msg.'</div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div class="error">'.$msg.'</div>';
            }
        }
    }
    unset($_SESSION['error']);
    echo "hello";
}
```

**UPDATED**

After reading your comments, this is related to javascript problem. You should add the id in `<div>` in order for it's works.

```
            if ($_SESSION['error'] == false) {
            echo '<div id="noError" class="noError">'.$msg.'</div>';
            } else {
                echo '<div id="error" class="error">'.$msg.'</div>';
            }
```

Comment: in my other functions that perform other actions, i store any messages in an array like $msgs[]  then i set the session varaible to equal my array varaible, thus making the session variable have more than 1 value.   everything works properly and shows right except i cant trigger the javascript to hide the message because the id/class of the div can't be found as its not there......but visibly i can see it (not visible on the vew page source)

Comment: you always unset `$_SESSION['userMsg']` in end of function, how you make sure it is not null or empty? Provide your function then.

Comment: $_SESSION['error'] = false;
   $msgs[] = "Client Added Successfully!";
   $_SESSION['userMsg'] = $msgs;

Comment: in comment you said you didn't use DOM/Ajax. If you can see it, you can view the code in the view source. Is the "Client Added Successfully!" showed up?

Comment: maybe i misunderstood...it shows up, but my javascript won't fire because the code isn't showing up.....i updated my questions

Comment: You didnt put any your javascript, nothing wrong with your code.

Comment: this is what i don't understand....why does it now show in the view source....its like its not there, but it is.  here is my javascript, placed at the bottom of my index page.   var ele = $("#noError");
   setTimeout(function() { ele.hide(); }, 5000);
   
   var ele = $("#error");
   setTimeout(function() { ele.hide(); }, 5000);

Comment: that shows those as looking for id elements because i was playing around trying to figure it out, but in either case, it doesn't fire because the html is not rendered

Comment: this is related to javascript question not even php function question, and you not put any javascript in your question. We can't solve your problem without it.

Comment: no the question is why is my html not showing when i view my source....the javascript piece works when the html is rendered.

Comment: Your question is out of topic and the code you provided is not related at all. All DOM/Ajax can not be viewed by view source code. Unless you do DOM Inspector like Barmar said in comment. Please do research first. View facobook or twitter or any website based on Javascript framework. You can not view any of text in there with view source.

Comment: whats the difference between my first set of functions and last part where i updated.....there is no AJAX.  the bottom - updated- function shows the html, the top portion doesn't.  forget the javascript, it was only mentioned as it doesn't work because the html outputted by the php function is not being shown in the view source.

Comment: ok, so i have commented out the unset($_SESSION['userMsg'] at the end of the message function and now it shows the html in the view source.  since that seems to be what is stopping my html from showing, how can i unset the session variable a different way?